# Need to clear MySession data before Logging out successfully using Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

this is my first time to build a web application. I want to use ajax to access Loggingout function in Default.aspx to empty MySession. Ajax calling returns as success instead of error however MySession has not been cleared.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Logout2").click(function (e) {
                alert(99);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Default.aspx/Loggingout',
                    data: '{a}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        window.location = '<%=this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Default.aspx")%>';
                },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(0);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have placed alert for testing and it doesn't go to error side which is alert(0). It has successfully return to Default page without clearing MySession. I have tried putting break point on the Loggingout function but it doesn't run in that function.

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
[WebMethod]
public static string Loggingout(string a)
{
    CarPark.MySession.Current.UserID = Guid.Empty;
    CarPark.MySession.Current.Username = "";
    CarPark.MySession.Current.UserEmail = "";
    CarPark.MySession.Current.UserRole = "";
    return "done";
}
```

This is the function written in Default.aspx page.

```
public class MySession
{
    // private constructor
    private MySession()
    {
        UserID = Guid.Empty;
        Username = "";
        UserEmail = "";
        UserRole = "";
    }
    // Gets the current session.
    public static MySession Current
    {
        get
        {
            MySession session =
              (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new MySession();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

In case you want to review MySession

Comment: what kind of session are you using? it seems to me that you are using a custom Session object? Or do you use the builtin Session?

Comment: So the breakpoint never gets hit in the LoggingOut method?  Or does is the break point not active while running?  Can you confirm LoggingOut runs?  How are you storing your session data?

Comment: I assume you are not getting "done" in the success msg variable. What do you get? It's clear your call is not reaching your web method because your breakpoint is not firing, which explains why the session is not cleared, unless you are not hooking the debugger correctly. Please modify your success signature and post all the information returned so we can help you. it should look like this:  function (data, textStatus, jqXHR).

Comment: Yea, i'm not getting "done" in success msg, the msg appears as [object Object]

Comment: Inspect that object in the dev console. It should tell you what's going on. Post it here.

Comment: the problem is, you did not clear your Session. Instead of clearing the values call `HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();` Or just call `HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = new MySession();` in your `LoggingOut` method.

Comment: Additionally you also need to signout the user the way you sign in the user. I mean if you have used FormsAuthentication to singin the user than you need to use it to signout the user. This will invalidate the authcookie created at the time of signing in.

Comment: It looks like you're utilizing the default Session within HttpContext.  Either call the `Clear` method, or `Remove` to remove it.  But, remember a session by default only exist for twenty minutes I believe.

Comment: Also, when you initially build this Session is it in a master page under some criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Loggingout(string a)
{
    // if you use FormsAuthentication call this.
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    // You can clear your session....
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();

    // ... or just set your session to a new object.
    HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = new MySession();

    return "done";
}
```

Comment: thanks ! :D but i found out there's another problem which is my ajax is not working well as it doesn't hit the Loggingout function. I have tried modifying success part in ajax -> success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR). it came out data = [object Object], status = "success", jqXHR = [object Object] . What does the object mean?

Comment: take a look here -> [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: ... just `alert(jqXHR.status + ' : ' + jqXHR.statusText);` and post the output of it.

Comment: ... and change the `data` property in your ajax request to: `data: '{ a: "SOME TEXT"}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Session.Abandon() Method
```

The Abandon method destroys all the objects stored in a Session object and releases their resources. If you do not call the Abandon method explicitly, the server destroys these objects when the session times out.

ref :- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx